# Binding visibility of a control depending on the state of a string attribute in my viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a string property in my viewmodel called "`CurrentTool`". How can I bind the visibility of a control depending on the state of the currentTool?

This for example does not work:

```
<DockPanel Visibility="{Binding (CurrentTool == brush), Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

I know that I can create some boolean properties in my viewmodel such as CurrentToolIsBrush and just bind to that, but I want to know if there is a simpler cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QuickConverter to convert inline in XAML (https://quickconverter.codeplex.com/)

In your case you could use something like:

```
Visibility="{qc:MultiBinding '$P0==$P1 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed', P0={Binding CurrentTool}, P1={Binding brush}}"
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you know if I can set P1 directly to the string literal or will I need to always bind it to something. For example, is it possible to do '$P0==brush' some way? I tried this but it doesnt work.

Comment: I think instead of writing P1={Binding...} you can define P1='brush' and use it in your comparison but I haven't checked that

Comment: alternatively try escaping the string like \'brush\', then you should be able to avoid declaration of P1

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom style with `DataTrigger`s

```
<DockPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentTool}" Value="brush">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DockPanel.Style>
```